# Fill an empty vector with a value at a certain sample

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm trying to figure out how to form an audio file, probably by using a series of loops.

I have a variables:

```
AudioVec = zeros(1,88200);
Values is a 1x30006 double
Arrival is a 1x30006 double
```

. AudioVec is the audio vector to be filled
. Values is the set of values to be placed into the audio vector
. Arrival is the time at which (in samples) the value is to be placed into the audio vector.

Comment: `Values = (1,30006)` is not valid syntax. Also, you say `AudioVec` is empty, but it's not, according to the first line of code. Please reword your question

Comment: and how should the output look like ?

Comment: For instance Arrival (1,1) = 720, Values(1,1) = 1.1 When Audiovec(1,720) let it equal 1.1 else 0. @LuisMendo